# how to make easy localization button to switch languages in the application?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, package, flutter-easy-localization

I'm using easy Localization Package in 2 languages Application ,,And I Need To swith langauge using a Button . How could i Do That?

```
  await EasyLocalization.ensureInitialized();
  log(token);
  runApp(
    EasyLocalization(
      supportedLocales: const [Locale('ar'), Locale('en')],
      path: 'assets/translations',
      startLocale: const Locale('ar'),
      fallbackLocale: const Locale('en'),
      saveLocale: true,
      assetLoader: const CodegenLoader(),
      child: ScreenUtilInit(
        designSize: const Size(411.4, 683.4),
        child: const MyApp(),
        builder: (context, child) => child!,
      ),
    ),
  );
```

Comment: see my answer I hope that will help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to import easy localization package

```
import 'package:easy_localization/easy_localization.dart'
```

Then pass a parameter ('ar' or 'en')

```
ElevatedButton(
   onPressed: () {
      setState(() {context.setLocale(Locale('en')); //ar});
                                  },
```

Answer (score 1):

This is enough:

```dart
await context.setLocale(Locale('es')); // change `easy_localization` locale
```

An important thing to note for those who use GetX. If you use a GetMaterialApp instead of a MaterialApp, you need to refresh GetX after updating EasyLocalization:

```dart
final newLocale = Locale('es');
await context.setLocale(newLocale); // change `easy_localization` locale
Get.updateLocale(newLocale); // change `Get` locale direction
```

Answer (score 0):

There is lesson explain the right way to make it:

[Source_code_in_github](https://github.com/A-bahattab/applocalization)

[Explain Localization with provider and shared preferences](https://youtu.be/pciUFlU0zWY)

There are some steps you should follow:

1. Add packages `provider` and `shared_preferneces`.
2. Create folder name it as `l10n`.
3. Add language json file in `l10n` folder as `*.arb` i.e `app_ar.arb` and `app_en.arb`.
4. Add Dart file in `l10n` folder name it: `l10n.dart`.
5. Write what you need in `arb` files like this: `"youKey":"your_value` first letter of key must be small letter camelCase, no _ nor -. i.e

```
{
    "application": "application",
    "setting": "settings",
    "langAR": "Arabic",
    "langEN": "English",
    "blue": "blue",
    "green": "green",
    "purple": "purple"
}
```

6. add your list language to `l10n.dart`.

```
    import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

    class L10n {
      static final all = [const Locale('ar'), const Locale('en')];
    }
```

7. Create `l10n.yaml` file in the root space of your project and write in it:

```
arb-dir: lib/l10n
template-arb-file: app_en.arb
out-localization-file: app_local.dart
```

8. Then in your terminal run `flutter pub get` that will generate the classes that contain all you properties of your languages.
9. Add new dart file name i.e `app_local.dart` with this code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_gen/gen_l10n/app_localizations.dart';

class AppLocal {
  static AppLocalizations? _loc;

  static AppLocalizations get loc {
    return AppLocal._loc!;
  }

  static void init(BuildContext context) {
    _loc = AppLocalizations.of(context);
  }
}
```

10. Add dart file name it i.e `setting_provider.dart`:

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

class SettingProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  String? local;
  updateLocal(String? lang) {
    local = lang;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

11. Add dart file name it i.e `shared_pref.dart`:

```
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class SharedPref {
  static String? lang;

  static addLang(String lang) async {
    SharedPreferences sp = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    sp.setString('lang', lang);
  }

  static Future<String?> getLang() async {
    SharedPreferences sp = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    lang = sp.getString('lang');
    return lang;
  }
}
```

12. Write in your `main` function:

```
Future<void> main(List<String> args) async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await SharedPref.getLang();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

and then in `MyApp` class return the provider like:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => SettingProvider())
      ],
      child: Builder(
        builder: (context) {
          return MaterialApp(
            supportedLocales: L10n.all,
            locale: Locale(Provider.of<SettingProvider>(context).local ??
                SharedPref.lang ??
                'en'),
            localizationsDelegates: AppLocalizations.localizationsDelegates,
            title: 'Localization',
            home: const HomePage(),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

13. Finally call the language in any class as in my example `HomePage`:

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    AppLocal.init(context);
    SettingProvider prov = Provider.of(context);
    
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(AppLocal.loc.application),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Wrap(
            children: List.generate(L10n.all.length, (index) {
              return RadioListTile(
                title: Text(
                  L10n.all[index].languageCode == 'en'
                      ? AppLocal.loc.langEN
                      : AppLocal.loc.langAR,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 28,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                  ),
                ),
                value: L10n.all[index].languageCode,
                groupValue: prov.local,
                onChanged: (String? value) {
                  SharedPref.addLang(value!);
                  prov.updateLocal(value);
                },
              );
            }),
          ),
          Center(
            child: Text(
              AppLocal.loc.setting,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 28,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```